# How to add an new array to an existing array and return a new array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add an new array to an existing array.

For example the existing array is

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

And now I have a new array which is

```
[7,8,9]
```

How can I get

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried to use the spread operator, but haven't figured it out.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] even if it's wrong. `arr1.push(arr2)` is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push it:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
const arr2 = [7,8,9];
arr.push(arr2);
```

Or use the spread operator:

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
const arr2 = [7,8,9];
arr = [...arr, arr2];
```